# RGB LED lights and Arduino

Tags: rgb-led

I am doing my thesis project which is a kinetic light/sound sculpture. My first step is to learn how to work with RGB LED lights and how to choose them and what other kinds of equipment I need.

I started to learn Arduino uno and learned how to light an LED, now I need to expand it much bigger. 
I want to be able to control each LEDs.

I want 30 meters LED light divided to 7 channels, in which each channel have a unique function that will trigger 7 channels of sound.

I hope I could use your help and thanks in advance for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use RGB Led Driver like: [WS2812](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812.pdf). 
You can build led strip as long as you want.

There are a lot of example/tutorial using Arduino and Strip Led composed by **WS2812** Led Driver (For example, [here](https://core-electronics.com.au/tutorials/ws2812-addressable-leds-arduino-quickstart-guide.html) there is a tutorial).

NB: You pay attention that using 30 meters strip led, you need an external power supply and you can't use 5V pin of Arduino, because Arduino doesn't supply sufficient power for supply a strip led too long.

Comment: Thank you so much. do I also need these? I found it on 1 tutorial :    

-1 x 220-440 Ohm Resistor (anything between these two values is fine)
-1 x 100-1000 microFarad Capacitor (anything between these two values is fine)
-5V power supply

Comment: Yes, how many strip do you need?

Comment: it is complicated if I am gonna just explain it without showing you any layouts but I try my best. So 30 meters stripe divided into 7 channels, each channel has a unique function and is made of 8 to 16 pieces from 10 cm to 60 cm. It's a modular/ parametric/algorithmic design.

Comment: Ideally, you would have a resistor between the Arduino pin and the first WS2812B for each strip. 7 strips  could be driven from 7 pins. Everytime you update a strip, the # of LEDs x 3 is how many bytes of data get sent out. You could also do it as one very long strip - the amount of data being sent out for a color change is then 7 times as much.  Adafruit.com has a  neopixel library for driving these LEDs, and fastled.h is another option.  Ex: here are four rings with 43 or 44 WS2812B each that I made, all are connected via individual wires to a 5V/10A supply, each has its own data line

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGOxbehyoM4&t=37s

Comment: and another question is that I have 6 PWM pins, can I add one to it ?